# Blazor WebAssembly SignalR HubConnection causing javascript error on reload

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I have a SignalR `HubConnection` within my Blazor WebAssembly application and whilst it works most of the time, if I reload the page (via the browser reload) then I often am getting the following error in the console and the connection is not made:

> Uncaught Error: The delegate target that is being invoked is no longer available.  Please check if it has been prematurely GC'd.
> at Object.invoke_delegate (dotnet.5.0.4.js:1)
> at WebSocket. (dotnet.5.0.4.js:1)

Here's a rough, simplified view of the code where I create the `HubConnection` (and dispose it).

```
@inherits LayoutBase
@attribute [Authorize]

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        //...
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        //...
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

```
public class LayoutBase : LayoutComponentBase, IAsyncDisposable
{
    [Inject] public IAccessTokenProvider AccessTokenProvider { get; set; }
    
    private readonly HubConnection _hubConnection;
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol(c =>
                    {
                        //...
                    })
                    .WithUrl(notificationHubUrl, option => option.AccessTokenProvider = GetAccessToken)
                    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                    .Build();                   
                    
        _hubConnection.Closed += HubConnectionOnClosed;
        _hubConnection.Reconnected += HubConnectionOnReconnected;
        _hubConnection.Reconnecting += HubConnectionOnReconnecting;
        
        await _hubConnection.StartAsync()
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }   
    
    private async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        var tokenResult = await AccessTokenProvider.RequestAccessToken(...)
        // etc...
    }
    
    // .. Event Handlers
    
    public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Disposing Hub: {_hubConnection.ConnectionId}");

        _hubConnection.Closed -= HubConnectionOnClosed;
        _hubConnection.Reconnected -= HubConnectionOnReconnected;
        _hubConnection.Reconnecting -= HubConnectionOnReconnecting;

        return _hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

Previously I had it as an injected service but I eventually simplified it to this structure but it continues to get this error on reload.  It's not every time I reload but most times.

I have tried changing the dispose pattern without success.  I can't find any information on the error anywhere else.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the non-`async` implementation of `IDisposable`? You keyword *sometimes* implies it's not being disposed properly.

Comment: Yeah, I have -though the `HubConnection` itself only has an async dispose...

Comment: I don't have the answer to the question, but I am currently experiencing the same issue (and still investigating). Have you tried to remove other parts of your code (other than what is for the SignalR connection) ? During my investigations I've found that it sometimes reduced the frequency of this issue, although it is for me something that's intermittent.

Comment: @user3918555 I've tried mucking about with scopes but no luck.  It only occasionally happens, but I have noticed that it usually logs the error twice.  I'm wondering if it might be caused by the OpenId auth flow causing multiple, overlapping, loads of my Blazor Wasm app..

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive answer as to the underlying reason but I suspect that this is a [bug somewhere in the SignalR/dotnet framework](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/32386) resulting in the GCing of a delegate because something drops a reference to it.

One way I've managed to provoke this error reasonably consistently is to have a handler returning just a `Task`, e.g.

```
_hubConnection.On<TEvent>(eventType.Name, OnEvent);
```

where OnEvent looks like this:

```
// THIS IS THE BROKEN SIGNATURE - DO NOT USE
private async Task OnEvent<TEvent>(TEvent e)
{
}
```

A workaround which *appears* to have fixed it for me is to make the handler actually return something. This seems to make something deeper in the framework hold a reference for longer so that it doesn't get GC'ed. E.g.

```
// WORKS ON MY MACHINE - Note the return type of Task<object>
private async Task<object> OnEvent<TEvent>(TEvent e)
{
  // ... Do stuff
  return null;
}
```